# Finish The Pattern

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Please note I realize there could be many "correct answers" but I'm looking for a specific one.

1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 8, 2, 9, 3, 5, 2, 42, 35, 42, 52, 55, 52, 109, 85, 120, ?, ?, ?

Hint:

> It has to do with multiplying, each "part" being multiplied, is multiplied by the part before it.

Hint2:

> Split it up into 9s.

Hint3:

> After splitting it up into 9s, split it up Again into 3s

Hint4: (ONLY USE THIS IF YOU HAVE TO)

> Think matrices.

When you answer please include which hints you used.

Comment: I used the hint, but still did not find the logic.

Comment: @Rafe Keep looking!

Comment: I give up! It is hard to realize how 42 is the next number after ...,3,5,2. and I found 3,5,4,2,...,35,42,... . That was interesting :)

Comment: @Rafe It is pretty complicated perhaps I'll add another hint?

Comment: How should the multiplying work, if 109 is a prime number?

Comment: Time to add a new hint I see...

Comment: Can you please explain, how 109 should be the result of multiplying "parts" ? I'm sorry to say, but if I could, I would gave down voted already. It isn't particularly funny to solve, nor does anything add up so far ...

Comment: If I give anymore information you guys will solve it easily, have you used the hints?

Comment: I sure did, and still I am as smart as I was before...

Comment: Could you give a hint as to what numbers in the sequence are used to calculate the next number? Like the entire sequence before it, or some numbers? Like the 3 numbers before it? I know it can't be the 2 numbers before it because `9,3,` for example is two times in it with a different number following it.

Comment: The last and final hint has been edited in.

Comment: The puzzle is actually quite good once we got the clues. SUGGESTION: start the riddle off like "You are stuck in the Matrix, and all you see is a monitor with these numbers and door. The door is locked with a 9-number code. Crack the code."

Comment: @d'alar haha, that's an interesting way to start it off, but then it would be too obvious as to multiplying matrices.

Comment: @warspyking Well, something _like_ that might work :p

Comment: In my opinion, since this puzzle is asking us to continue an arbitrary number sequence, it is an assumption puzzle in the spirit of the unsuccessful Security to the Party puzzles. I think this is why you're getting downvotes on this question, unfortunately. See http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/should-whats-the-missing-number-in-the-series-x-be-allowed and http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the missing 3 numbers are: 879, 750, 934.

I had to use all of the hints!

The answer can be derived by taking each group of 9 to represent a 3x3 matrix, then multiplying it with the preceding group of 9. There are 3 given, and the 3rd has been derived from the first 2. So let's take the 2nd and the 3rd:

```
3, 4, 5, 
8, 2, 9, 
3, 5, 2 
X    
42, 35, 42, 
52, 55, 52, 
109, 85, 120
=
879, 750, 934
1421, 1155, 1520
604, 550, 626
```

Comment: I'd have to check the calculations to see if it's right, but how you got it is exactly correct! +1 for providing the whole next matrix, not just 3 numbers.

Comment: @warspyking Thanks :) I left another comment in the main question too. I think it's good